# What is "type ascription" referring to in this case?

Tags: enums, rust, match, println, arity

What is error ascription referring to in this case and how can I fix my code to println based on the arity passed in?

Running the code below throws the error:

```
error: expected type, found `10`
  --> src/main.rs:21:27
   |
21 |    tellTime(Clock:Sundial(10));
   |                           ^^ expecting a type here because of type ascription
```

**main.rs:**

```
enum Clock {
    Sundial(u8),
    Digital(u8, u8),
    Analog(u8, u8, u8),
}

fn tellTime(clock: Clock) {
    match clock {
      Clock::Sundial(hours) =>
          println!("Time is: {}", hours),
      Clock::Digital(hours, mins) =>
          println!("Time is: {}:{}", hours, mins),
      Clock::Analog(hours, mins, secs) =>
          println!("Time is: {}:{}:{}", hours, mins, secs),
      _ => println!("Not a clock!")

    }

}
fn main() {
   tellTime(Clock:Sundial(10));
}
```

Comment: You have a typo. You meant `Clock::Sundial(10)` — **two** colons.

Comment: Idiomatic Rust uses `snake_case` for variables, methods, macros, fields and modules; `UpperCamelCase` for types and enum variants; and `SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE` for statics and constants. Use `tell_time` instead, please.

Comment: Note that this does **not** match on arity — that's not possible. This matches on the **name** of the enum variant. The variants happen to have different arity, but they don't need to.

Comment: I bought your series btw ;) I'm literally going through it lol. I'm sure you noticed lol

Comment: That's wonderful! I did think to myself that the sundial example seemed familiar, but I chalked it up to just being a common example ^_^